# I have a 1gbit wifi plan but my speeds are limited to 500mbps. What do I do?

Tags: networking

I have a plan of Frontier's 1 gbps wifi but the speeds are capped at 50%.

My status page clearly says that my link speed should be 1,000 mbps.
[image]

But when I do a speed test (I used Ookla) these are my results.
[image]

My download speed is as I said, capped at 50%. I've tried looking around on Google for an answer
but I haven't found anything. Anyone have a solution on this?
Or does this happen on purpose? I'm not sure.

Comment: Link speed is the maximum potential speed of the Ethernet connection. Every gigabit Ethernet connection shows a link connection of 1,000 mbps.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 given the context, that's probably his GPON WAN link speed, not Ethernet *per se*, but your point still applies.

Comment: Try wired connection?

Answer (score 3):

Most people that ask this kind of question do so because they mistakenly assumed that 1Gbps Internet service that also supports Wi-Fi will thus support 1Gbps Wi-Fi to an arbitrary Wi-Fi client device. Unfortunately that assumption is still only rarely true as of early 2023.

1 gigabit per second Internet service will support 1 gigabit per second wired Ethernet speeds (which, after overhead, maxes out at about 943Mbps). So be sure to test your speed over Ethernet directly off the back of your ONT or modem (or your main router if it has an integrated ONT or modem).

Gigabit Wi-Fi generally requires 160MHz-wide channels, which a lot of routers and client devices don't support, and the 160MHz-wide channel must be reasonably free of interference, which is hard to come by in populated areas. It also requires both the router and the client in question to support at least two spatial streams, but that's fairly common nowadays.

It's important to know that you don't get faster Wi-Fi just by upgrading your residential broadband internet service speed or just by upgrading your wireless router if your client device's Wi-Fi radio hardware is still a bottleneck. You must pay attention to the technical details of the capabilities of your Wi-Fi client hardware too.

Updated to add: I forgot to mention that wireless signal strength matters as well, so even if you have your 2x2:2 AC or AX router set to use a clean 160MHz-wide channel, and your client supports all that too, you should test with your client within say 5 meters of the router with clear line-of-sight (no walls or cabinet doors or other furniture in the way). But don't go too close, because too much signal strength can overload the receiver as well and cause distortion. So keep your client at least 1-2 meters away from your AP. Shoot for an RSSI below -40 but above -60dBm.